# Scroll code block instead of wrapping text

Tags: css, block-editor

I'm including some code in a blog post and the length of some lines causes text to wrap, which I don't want.[image: wrapped text code]

I'd like to have the sort of thing which can be found here on stackexchange, where a scroll bar is added for long code to prevent line breaks.

```
tttttttttttttthhhhhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiissssssssssssssssss iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiissssssssssssssssss vvvvvveeeeeeeerrrrrrrryyyyyyyyy llllllllooooooonnnnnnnnnnnnnggggggggggg
```

After some research I've tried adding this custom CSS class:

```
.scroll {
  white-space: pre;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

But this has had no effect on the code block. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using blocks?

Try to add a code block, give it an additional class **scroll** - and adjust your css like:

```
.scroll code {
  white-space: pre;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Should work then.